# I am using Firebase RealTime Database.. I want to list ascending on Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble based on the number of digits in string listing ..

I want the field named "score" to be sorted from higher to lower, but for example, there are 10 users, 9 of them have score with 5 digits, while 1 user has score with 6 digits, so I want the higher score to be on top of the list which is with 6 digits as I mentioned above but once the score becames 6 digits it goes at the end of the list which should be on top..

How can I solve this problem .. ??

```
Query query = ref.child("Kullanıcılar").orderByChild("puan");
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        list.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            i++;
            user = ds.getValue(User.class);
            list.add(i +" - "+ user.getIsim().toString() + " " + user.getPuan().toString());
            //list.add(user.getIsim().toString() + " " + user.getPuan().toString());
        }
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Collections.reverse(list);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

JSON:

```
{
  "Kullanıcılar": {
    "5bdhzNz3SlhzcCAYJaDpJyeppSx2": {
        "email": "egemenn1453@gmail.com",
        "id": "5bdhzNz3SlhzcCAYJaDpJyeppSx2"
        "isim": "egemen"
        "puan": "24000"
    },
    "7iJJxUswPPhkLXfm6LNHNCCRSeJ3": {
        "email": "kalantolga@hotmail.com",
        "id": "7iJJxUswPPhkLXfm6LNHNCCRSeJ3",
        "isim": "falanfilan",
        ,
        "puan": "25000"
    },
    "JoSwIRjzrxTHTz7CXaiQLAjQMCZ2": {
        "email": "terketyaman160@gmail.com",
        "id": "JoSwIRjzrxTHTz7CXaiQLAjQMCZ2"
        "isim": "fropsello",
        "puan": "56525"
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're storing the scores as strings, instead of as numbers. Can you edit your question to include the JSON at `ref.child("Kullanıcılar")` (as text, no screenshots)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: How can I do this?? I dont know.. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm trying to help, but need to see your JSON. How to get it I already explained, same as on your previous question. You can then add it to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it.

Comment: "Kullanıcılar" : {
    "5bdhzNz3SlhzcCAYJaDpJyeppSx2" : {
      "email" : "egemenn1453@gmail.com",
      "id" : "5bdhzNz3SlhzcCAYJaDpJyeppSx2"
      "isim" : "egemen"      
      "puan" : "24000"
    },
    "7iJJxUswPPhkLXfm6LNHNCCRSeJ3" : {
      "email" : "kalantolga@hotmail.com",
      "id" : "7iJJxUswPPhkLXfm6LNHNCCRSeJ3",
      "isim" : "falanfilan",    ,
      "puan" : "25000"
    },
    "JoSwIRjzrxTHTz7CXaiQLAjQMCZ2" : {
      "email" : "terketyaman160@gmail.com",
      "id" : "JoSwIRjzrxTHTz7CXaiQLAjQMCZ2"
      "isim" : "fropsello",     
      "puan" : "56525"
    },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're storing the scores as strings, Firebase will sort them on their lexicographical (string) value. In lexicographical order "9" is after "10", because "9" > "1". This may seem illogical at first, but is completely correct.

The recommended solution is to store your scores as numbers:

```
{
  "Kullanıcılar": {
    "5bdhzNz3SlhzcCAYJaDpJyeppSx2": {
        "email": "egemenn1453@gmail.com",
        "id": "5bdhzNz3SlhzcCAYJaDpJyeppSx2"
        "isim": "egemen"
        "puan": 24000
    },
    "7iJJxUswPPhkLXfm6LNHNCCRSeJ3": {
        "email": "kalantolga@hotmail.com",
        "id": "7iJJxUswPPhkLXfm6LNHNCCRSeJ3",
        "isim": "falanfilan",
        "puan": 25000
    },
    "JoSwIRjzrxTHTz7CXaiQLAjQMCZ2": {
        "email": "terketyaman160@gmail.com",
        "id": "JoSwIRjzrxTHTz7CXaiQLAjQMCZ2"
        "isim": "fropsello",
        "puan": 56525
    }
}
```

Now the nodes are numeric and will be correctly sorted, since `10` > `9` in numeric sort order.

Comment: I understood.. How can I do in Android Studio with code?

Comment: If you change the scores in your database to be numeric, you won't have to change your code.